# require('../') in a script in the node_modules/.bin

Tags: node.js, sequelize-cli, sequelize-auto

I am trying to figure out how the sequelize auto script works in the node_modules directory of a node project.

The very first statement has me stumped:

`var sequelizeAuto = require('../');`

I don't understand why or how this works [how can you include a whole directory as a package?

Perhaps the runner (npx sequelize-auto) provides a special environment? How do I figure it out?

[github: sequelize-auto script](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto/blob/master/bin/sequelize-auto)

Comment: I'm not sure, but i think if the require-function does point to a directory instead of a single file, the directory will be searched for a index.js-file which will be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative paths fallback to `index.js` if no file is mentioned.

```
var sequelizeAuto = require('../');
```

The above line is essentially a shorthand for :

```
var sequelizeAuto = require('../index.js');
```

Comment: This is missing the part which would describe how node handles symlinks in `.bin` (as otherwise `..` would point to `node_modules` instead of specific module).